# Jquery hide parent ul

Tags: jquery

I have the following div which contains a select list of tags (categories) which, when selected filter (hide) any li containing the word selected.  This works well, however I would actually like it to hide the parent .

For example if Neurology was selected, I would want to have Heading 2 and its parent ul still visible along with Neurology.  If Diabetes is selected, I would want the parent ul to be hidden completely.

Can anyone help with this?

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <select id="tags">
       <option>Cancer</option>
       <option>Diabetes</option>
       <option>Obesity</option>
    </select>

    <ul class="itemdetails">
       <li class="heading">Heading 1</li>
       <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Diabetes</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="itemdetails">
       <li class="heading">Heading 2</li>
       <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Obesity</span></a></li>
       <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Neurology</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
var itemlist = $('#container');
$('#tags').change( function () {
    var tagsfilter = $(this).val();
    if (tagsfilter) {
        $matches = $(itemlist).find('span.tagdetails:Contains(' + tagsfilter + ')').parent();
         $('a', itemlist).not($matches).hide();
        $matches.show();
    } else {
        $(itemlist).find("a").show();
    }
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Well, immediate red flag is `'span.tagdetails:Contains('` contains should be lowercased

Comment: Also as a side note; `itemlist` is already a jQuery object, so don't do `$(itemlist)` and try to re-wrap it, as it's pointless.  And `$('a', itemlist)` should be just `itemlist.find('a')`

Comment: *"If Diabetes is selected, I would want the parent ul to be hidden completely."* Do you mean the parent ul of Neurology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated code.**

1) `$('.tagdetails:not(:contains("'+tagsfilter +'"))').closest('li').hide();`

First we select and hide all the `li` elements which does not contain value text of the selected option.

2) `$('.itemdetails:not(:has(li:visible>a>span))').not('.heading').hide();`

Next we select all the `ul` elements with class itemdetails which has visible `li` child element which in turn has descendants `a` and `span` and does not have a heading class and hide it.

```js
$('#tags').change( function () {

    $('.itemdetails').show();
    $('.tagdetails').closest('li').show();
    
    var tagsfilter = $(this).val();  
    if($('.tagdetails:contains("'+tagsfilter+'")').length > 0){
       $('.tagdetails:not(:contains("'+tagsfilter +'"))').closest('li').hide();
       $('.itemdetails:not(:has(li:visible>a>span))').not('.heading').hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <select id="tags">
        <option>Cancer</option>
        <option>Diabetes</option>
        <option>Obesity</option>
        <option>Others</option>
    </select>

    <ul class="itemdetails">
        <li class="heading">Heading 1</li>
        <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Diabetes</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="itemdetails">
        <li class="heading">Heading 2</li>
        <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Obesity</span></a></li>
        <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Neurology</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="itemdetails">
        <li class="heading">Heading 3</li>
        <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Diabetes</span></a></li>
        <li><a href><span class="tagdetails">Others</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fantastically, however I notice that if Diabetes also featured under say a Heading 3, it doesn't show either of them

Comment: For that case to be handled the code will require sm changes.I will try to update the solution soon

Comment: The code has been updated to select and display duplicate values under different headings.Hope it helps.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Works like a charm. Thank you so much for your dedicated time on this.